# How to Prevent Javascript code runing multiple times caused by caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

I have an `Asp.net-MVC` that when I send the request it returns a `partial-view`.

```
public ActionResult AccountDetails()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/partials/Account/Details.cshtml");
}
```

Then I load partial in my form using code below.

```
var condition = true;
var pageNumber = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#page_view" + i).addClass("d-none");
    if (condition && $("#page_view" + i).html().trim() == "") {
        pageNumber = i;
        condition = false;
    }
}
$("#page_view" + pageNumber).removeClass("d-none");

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    async: true,

    success: function (result) {
        $("#page_view" + pageNumber).html(result);
    }
});
```

In my main html file I just use a link to get the page and load it:

```
<a href="javascript: load_main_form('Account/Details');">DetailsPage</a>
```

In this method the problem is when I load and close one page multiple times Javascript of that page stores in cache by every load and some functions or events runs multiple times by every load.

I used `ajaxComplete` to get how many times it store it in cache.

How can I clear cache or rewrite on last one?
Or even if there is a faster way to do this I will be thankful for sharing.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue:  `return View(` is not a partial view, it's a full view, so will include all the js etc from your _layout.  Try `return PartialView(`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case both of them compiles razor code and returns the result.

Comment: But it was better to use partialView thanks. I will update my question.

Comment: What's your main purpose? Try to use the most common patterns. This is recommended to use *jquery-unobtrusive*  dealing with `PartialView`. Otherwise, it's a hard job to fix your code without reproduction

Comment: *the problem is when I load and close one page multiple times Javascript of that page stores in cache* - this is due to your (mis)understanding of what you're doing.  You're creating a Single Page Application (SPA) by load the next "page" via ajax and .html(result).  You're not "loading and *closing*" anything, you have one page.

Comment: You need a paradigm-shift into the SPA way of thinking - one solution may be to load *all* your javascript up front and don't have any in the partial views.  Another may be to check which "page" is currently loaded at the start of each script and exit if the script is not for that page.

Comment: Yes It suppose to be a single page that loads different html and javascripts in same page. So isn't there any way to clear cache or some thing to fix this? and what is that exit you said? When I run a script block any function inside it stores inside cache and cause trouble.

Comment: How can jquery-unobtrusive help? Is any way to handle refreshless multipage in it? Sadly I don't know anything about it.

Comment: can you add main page and partial class cshtml with  minimum HTML. Also if you load partial view from anchor tag, then what ajax do?

Comment: Also everytime when you call the page, HTML will destroy (if assign HTML to inner side of same control ), bu javascript will be stay. For random URL, use Math.random- const sevenRandom = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 9000000);  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269075/javascript-to-navigate-to-random-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna address your question in steps

#### 1. "Javascript code runing multiple times caused by caching"

Cache does not cause code to run multiple times. Cache just affects how the code is loaded. If you attempt to load a js multiple times, cache will just affect where the browser is going to look for that file, either the web (if not cached) or the local cache. Your browser will never run any code just because is in the cache, it will run because you requested it to do (intentionally or unintentionally)

Most probably there is javascript code meant to run once inside of one of those views that you are loading. So if you have code meant to run once, it must be placed in the file that loads the rest of the views (usually called the layout, or the base)

Any javascript present in any of the views, must be specific for that view. So in order to debug that, go to any view causing issues and see if the javascript is there, if so, search the origin (maybe from the layout, maybe another partial view inside that partial view, or somwhere)

See the image below to understand what I mean
[image]

Now finally

#### 2. "How to Prevent Javascript code runing multiple times"

Yes, you can prevent code running multiple times, Ill explain how, but I advise you to first fix the structure of your proyect and only use this in the cases where structure cannot change, as otherwise it would be like puting paint on top of the cracks

lets say that you have some code:

```
let myCounter = 0;
myCounter ++;
console.log(`Hey! I've run ${myCounter} times`);
```

then inside the partial view, change the code and wrap it in a function together with a statement that checks if that has already run (you give it a name, lets say initializator, and then...)

```
!window.initializator && (initializator = true) && (function() {
    let myCounter = 0;
    myCounter++;
    console.log(`Hey! I've run ${myCounter} times`);
})()
```

now, no matter how many times the browser executes this fragment of code, it will never run the instructions inside more than once, because it leaves a variable in the global scope that ensures that if the code is executed again, the code will be skipped.

You can also use another object instead of window (which I highly recommend, because you must never use global variables if you can avoid them) but I put the example like that because of if you don't have control of the flow of your code, you cannot ensure to have an object instantiated before either.

Comment: For the first method the problem is I just want to use this statement inside one partial view and the others don't have the code. and what I understand is that `ajaxComplete` is a global event that in any cache it is it will run for any ajax call. But I think the second method will work but still is a dirty way.